# The meaning of Ezekiel 20:25?

Tags: torah-study, midrash, ezekiel--the-book, king-hezekiah

[**Ezekiel 20:24-26**](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.20.24-26?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> **Because they did not perform My ordinances, and they rejected My statutes and desecrated My Sabbaths, and their eyes were after the idols of their fathers. (25) I, too, gave them statutes that were not good and ordinances through which they should not live. (26) And I defiled them with their gifts, when causing to pass all who open the womb, in order that I lay them desolate, in order that they know that I am the Lord.**

What were those no-good statues in Ezekiel 20:25? Some people claim that those laws are some of the Torah's laws?!!

Answer (score 2):

See [Rashi there](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.20.25?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) who quotes the translation of Yonasan ben Uziel:

> statutes that were not good I delivered them into the hands of their temptation to stumble over their iniquity, and so did Jonathan render: And I delivered them into the hands of their foolish temptation, and they went and made decrees that were not good, and practices by which they cannot live.

[Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.20.25?lang=bi&p2=Radak_on_Ezekiel.20.25.1&lang2=bi) and [Metzudas David](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.20.25?lang=bi&with=Metzudat%20David&lang2=en) understand the verse to be saying: "I [delivered them into the hands of their enemies, who] gave them statues that were no good..."

Answer (score 1):

[Asher Weiser](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8_%D7%95%D7%99%D7%96%D7%A8) in his commentary on the verse explains that the laws and ordinances given by Hashem *seemed* not good because Yisrael interpreted them wrong.